# How to change scatter plot style in offline plots with Pandas plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm plotting scatter plots from a Pandas dataframe using plotly and embedding them into html. I have figured out how to define the data, the layout and generate the code needed to embed but am struggling to find a way to change the style of plot.

Specifically, I'd like to:

- Change the line style (e.g. from solid to dashed or dotted ... I figured out how to change from line to marker)
- Change the marker style and color
- Specify the color of each line or marker series

Below is a snippet from my code showing the plotting section. This code works fine in my script, I just can't figure out how to modify the appearance. Any help would be great!

Thanks :)

```
layout = go.Layout(
    title="This is the title",
    xaxis=dict(
        title="x-axis label",
        autorange=True,
        showgrid=True,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=False,
        ticks='',
        showticklabels=True,
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="y-axis label",
        autorange=True,
        showgrid=True,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=False,
        ticks='',
        showticklabels=True
    ),
    width=800,height=550
)

data=[
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["Timestamp"],
        y=df["Conditions1"],
        name="Trace 1",
        mode="markers",
        ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["Time"],
        y=df["Conditions2"],
        name="Trace 2",
        mode="markers"
        )
    ]

fig1 = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plot1 = plotly.offline.plot(fig1,
                            config={"displaylogo": False}, 
                            show_link=False, 
                            include_plotlyjs=True,
                            output_type='div')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your plot to have dots and lines you should set `mode="markers+lines"`, either way inside the scatter you can modify the `marker` and `line` objects:

```
go.Scatter(
    x=df["Time"],
    y=df["Conditions2"],
    name="Trace 2",
    mode="markers+lines",
    marker=dict(
        color="red", # or "rgb(255,0,0)" or "#ff0000" or even another pandas column
        size=7,
        symbol="cross",
        line=dict(
            # you can add here the properties for the outline of the markers
            color="green",
            width=1,
        )
    )
    line=dict(
        shape="linear", # or "spline" for instance, for a curvy line
        dash="dash", # or "dot", "dashdot", etc.
        color="blue",
        width=3,
    )
)
```

you can see all the available options in the [markers](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-marker) and [lines](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-line) reference.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thank you :)